# Gnatmake compilation returns a 255 exit status error, what should I do?

Tags: macos, compilation, ada

I started studying ADA, and basically copied the "Hello World" code just to check how to compile it.

I used this command to compile it:

```
     gnatmake hello.adb
```

And this is what I got:

```
     gcc -c hello.adb
     gnatbind -x hello.ali
     gnatlink hello.ali
     collect2: error: /usr/local/gnat/bin/nm returned 255 exit status
     gnatlink: error when calling /usr/local/gnat/bin/gcc
     gnatmake: *** link failed.
```

What should I do?
This might be helpful to know: I use Mac OS El Capitan, and I installed the GNAT-GPL 64-bit Darwin version.

EDIT:
I used the command

```
     gnatmake hello.adb -largs -Wl,-v
```

And it seemed things started working, but afterwards I would get the same error exit status, with the error message:

```
     gnatlink: error when calling /usr/local/gnat/bin/gcc
```

It got a suggestion to modify the ~/.bash_profile_common file, yet the terminal can't find it. Actually, my terminal doesn't seem to be capable to find a single file or directory if I type it with the "~/." or "~/" suffix. I will ask a question concerning this particular issue in another forum.

Comment: Not sure how you got just `nm` there? I see `gcc-nm` and `x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0-gcc-nm` (neither of which will actually _run_ since they call up a nonexistent dylib). Can you try `gnatmake hello.adb -largs -Wl,-v` (passes `-v` to the actual link stage, for more info).

Comment: I used this command, and it worked! Thank you! Will I need to use this command all the time?

Comment: I was hoping that it would still fail, but you would get more info, and you would either see what the problem was or post that info so we could debug further. You really shouldn’t need to do the extra stuff I suggested, it’s purely for diagnostic purposes. Does the original command now work? (you might need to say `gnatmake -f hello.adb` to force the rebuild).

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what is happening here, but now I get "gnatmake command not found". This is really weird. It was working well, if I type in "info gnatmake" it gives me a bunch of info, but once I compile a file, it gives me "command not found".

Comment: Ok, I managed to get rid of the "command not found" error by using this command "PATH="/usr/local/gnat/bin:$PATH"; export PATH". I typed in the "gnatmake -f hello.adb" commande, and this I got a new error: gnatlink: error when calling /usr/local/gnat/bin/gcc

Comment: I think you should edit `~/.bash_profile_common` to contain that PATH setting, then open a new Terminal window; at least PATH’d be consistent from then on. That aside, I’m stuck (without more details, anyway). What is your PATH? (and, you should [edit] your question to include more detail rather than using comments, which have very limited presentation facilities)

Comment: On OSX, it's just `~/.bash_profile` actually

Comment: @patrix, my `~/.bash_profile` (dated 23 Sep 2009, from my first Mac, a Powerbook) simply says `. ~/.bash_profile_common`, and I’ve gone along with it. I guess things have changed -- when?

Comment: @SimonWright I never had a `~/.bash_profile_common` on my Macs

Comment: @SimonWright @patrix I seem to be unable to locate both files, no `~/.bash_profile_common` nor `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Then create `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @SimonWright Where exactly should I create it?

Comment: `~` means your home directory (where you get to if you say just `cd`). So e.g. `cd; nano .bash_profile`.